# How to loop over a dataframe, writing certain fields to files, per each unique value of a column and name the file according to that column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a combined table for multiple IDs.

| ID | Type | Color | Size | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Wht | S | 7 |
| 1 | B | Ylw | L | 9 |
| 2 | A | Grn | S | 2 |
| 2 | C | Wht | M | 7 |
| 3 | B | Blk | M | 3 |

For each unique ID, I would like to write a text file, named `<ID>.txt`.

Within each file, I would like to write the Type and Color values. For example:

1.txt

```
AWht
BYlw
```

Here's what I have so far, but I am stuck on two things:

1. Insert ID values as the file names. It seems to only accept text strings.
2. Insert Type and Color values in the written contents of each file.

```py
import pandas as pd
data = [['1','A','Wht','S','7'],['1','B','Ylw','L','9'],['2','A','Grn','S','2'],['2','C','Wht','M','7'],['3','B','Blk','M','3']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID','Type','Color','Size','Quantity'])
IDs = df.ID.unique()
IDs.sort()
for i in IDs:
    with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('TypeColor')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
# Enhanced by @piRSquared
for name, subdf in df.groupby('ID'):
    data = subdf['Type'] + subdf['Color']
    data.to_csv(f'{name}.csv', index=False, header=None)

# Old answer
# for name, subdf in df.groupby('ID'):
#     with open(f'{name}.txt', 'w') as fp:
#         data = subdf['Type'] + subdf['Color']
#         data.to_csv(fp, index=False, header=None)
```

Output:

```
>>> %cat 1.txt
AWht
BYlw

>>> %cat 2.txt
AGrn
CWht

>>> %cat 3.txt
BBlk
```

Comment: I think `to_csv` offers the same protection as `with`.  You could simplify this to `for name, d in (df.Type + df.Color).groupby(df.ID): d.to_csv(f'{name}.txt', index=False, header=None)`

Comment: @piRSquared You are right. I updated my answer. I prefer to avoid the `(df.Type + df.Color)` before `groupby`. I'm not sure what the OP really wants.